# How can I get President Kimball to retreat to the safe room during the Arizona Killer quest?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I am trying to force Kimball to retreat to the safe room during the Legion quest "Arizona Killer." I am an Unarmed character, without a high enough Explosive or Repair skill to blow up the vertibird.

I have the key to the safe room, there has to be a way to get him in there! Do I just damage the vertibird while he is giving the speech? I don't have any guns, and punching the vertibird doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is how I solved this quest.

During President Kimball's speech, I snuck up to the Vertibird (use a Stealthboy or something) and damaged it with weapons. Not sure if you can use Unarmed weapons on it.

When the Vertibird catches fire you have to get away from it or the explosion will kill you. So sneak away, down the ladder, away from the blast. Once the Vertibird blows up the President is rushed into the safe room, where you can sneak in (or not, just charge in) and kill him.